# Insert an HTML table into sharepoint 2013 webpart script

Tags: html, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-list

I have a problem, I've created a simple webpart that perfoms basics CRUD OPERATIONS, I wanted to add an HTML table to format and display the results retrieved from the READ operation, here is the code for a better understanding:

```
 function retriveListItem() {
  execute(
    "items?$orderby=Nom&$select=Nom,Cognom,Indirizz",
    "GET",
    "GET",
    null,
    function (data, status, xhr) {
        $("#result").empty();
        var string = "<table><tr><th>Nome</th><th>Cognome</th><th>Indirizzo</th></tr>";
        $("#result").append(string);
        string = string = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
          var item = data.d.results[i];
          string = "<tr><td>" + item.Nom + "</td><td>" + item.Cognom + "</td><td>" + item.Indirizz + "</td></tr>";
        $("#result").append(string);
      }
      string = "</table>";
     $("#result").append(string);
    },
    function (xhr, status, error) {
      $("#result").empty().text(error);
    });
}
```

But when the page is rendered in the browser if I hit the F12 key I discover that sharepoint automatically adds the tbody tag (which I haven't wrote) and it close the tag /table automatically in the wrong position here is the code rendered in the browser:

```
<div id="result">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
       <th>Nome</th>
       <th>Cognome</th>
       <th>Indirizzo</th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
<tr>
  <td>Giova</td>
  <td>Nardi</td>
  <td>Viale della Cagna, Verona</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Antonio</td>
  <td>Petrarca</td>
  <td>Via Camello 31, Rovegna</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Luca</td>
  <td>Mandelli</td>
  <td>Via Rossini, 32 Cesano Maderno</td>
</tr>
</div>
```

Does anybody knows why that? Any idea on how to workaround that issue? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like in your code, your string variable is just overwriting itself, and you are posting the results to the browser each time. Rather than using .append() each time you update the string, just use a `string += ....` and then append after the loops have run and the string is populated with the full table.

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maniccomputer/L0ek9Lyv/) as an example using your code (for the most part).

So your code would look like:

```
function retriveListItem() {
execute(
"items?$orderby=Nom&$select=Nom,Cognom,Indirizz",
"GET",
"GET",
null,
function (data, status, xhr) {
    $("#result").empty();
    var string = "<table><tr><th>Nome</th><th>Cognome</th><th>Indirizzo</th></tr>";
    //$("#result").append(string);
    //string = string = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
      var item = data.d.results[i];
      string += "<tr><td>" + item.Nom + "</td><td>" + item.Cognom + "</td><td>" + item.Indirizz + "</td></tr>";
    //$("#result").append(string);
  }
  string += "</table>";
 $("#result").append(string);
},
function (xhr, status, error) {
  $("#result").empty().text(error);
});
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The other option, if you have a lot of data, is to build the table first so the browser can create the table with any necessary CSS for the user to see, then add the rows with your data.

[Here is an alternate JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maniccomputer/Lv88z675/) as an example.

You can still use your append, but instead of appending to the #results element, you append it to the table _in_ the #results table.

Answer (score 0):

You can always insert HTML into an existing table using JQuery's `after()` method. Since you have a first `<tr>` already, you can poke in your built up HTML after that first row:

```
// First, put your basic table into #result
$("#result").html('<table id="resulttable"><tr><td>...</td></tr></table>');

// Next build up the necessary rows and columns
for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
    // Build up your string as above
}
// Next, poke it into the DOM after the first <tr>
$("#resulttable tr").first().after(string);
```

You will find a full mockup below. The `results` data and the code to populate rows is shown in the page's `<head>` section. Below that, in the `<body>` a table is defined with ID `mytab`. That ID is picked up in the code that populates the rows.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    data = { d : {
        results: [
            { Nom: 'nom1', Cognom: 'Cognom1', Indirizz: 'Indirrizz1' },
            { Nom: 'nom2', Cognom: 'Cognom2', Indirizz: 'Indirrizz2' },
            { Nom: 'nom3', Cognom: 'Cognom3', Indirizz: 'Indirrizz3' } ] } };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
            item = data.d.results[i]
            str = '<tr><td>' + item.Nom + '</td><td> ' + item.Cognom +
                '</td><td>' + item.Indirizz + '</td></tr>';
            $('#mytab tr').first().after(str);
        }
    });

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="mytab">
      <tr>
        <td>First column</td> <td>Second column</td> <td>Third column</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please can you be more specific, based on my example? I can't implement your solution, probably i don't understand something. Thanks a lot

Comment: I just added a mock up including some dummy data and the processing. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help,
It works as well, but i prefere the solution by ManiacComputer because is easier for me.